# How to match an exact string without using ^ and $

Tags: regex

I have a simple domain name like this: `https://example.com/` and I would like to match it against a string that may be or not the exact match.

The other variations might include:

```
https://example.com/1234567890/
https://example.com/subdomain/subdomain2
https://example.com/domain
```

etc

I would like to match the exact domain but without telling it where the string begins or ends.

I tried: `https:\/\/example\.com\/[^.]` hoping to negate anything after the string or `https:\/\/example\.com\/(?!.)` to negate the lookahead but that doesn't seem to work so I'm lost right now.

I need a regex that will match only `https://example.com/` from this list:

```
https://example.com/
https://example.com/1234567890/
https://example.com/subdomain/subdomain2
https://example.com/domain
```

Comment: Are you looking to match the example urls you gave, or for them not to match? For example, should `https://example.com/1234567890/` return a match, or not?

Comment: is this what your trying?  https://regex101.com/r/vQAW9R/1

Comment: Or this https://regex101.com/r/VfETHG/1

Comment: None of the above solutions work for me as they match all 3 urls and need to only match `https://example.com/`

Answer (score 2):

Considering that URLs don't contain whitespace. Then instead of `[^.]` you could essentially *just* use `[^\s]` or `\S`.

```
(?:^|\s)http\S+
```

[**Live Demo**](https://regex101.com/r/2Zaq7B/1)

Note that this assumes that all URLs start with `http` and that any character that isn't a whitespace, is part of the URL.

**Edit:**

Since you only want to match the domain, you could do something like:

```
(?:^|\s)(https?://\w+\.\w+/)
```

[**Live Demo**](https://regex101.com/r/2Zaq7B/2)

Comment: In this sentence containing <hxxps://www.google.com/>, with hxxps replaced by https (to disable to auto-link in comments), your regex would match `https://www.google.com/>,`. The OP needs to specify what can and cannot follow the URLs in the OP's strings. Until then, if you must answer, please state the assumptions you've made clearly, so that people can make a well-informed decision as to whether your answer would suffice for them.

Comment: @hvd that was actually my intend with the "Considering that URLs don't contain whitespace". However I have made it more clear now.

Comment: This doesn't work for as it matches  all urls and I only need to match `https://example.com/`

Comment: @faceoff I missed that you only wanted to match the domain and not the whole URL. Take a look at my edit.

Comment: No, I want a regex that will match only the element `https://example.com/` from this list: `https://example.com/
https://example.com/1234567890/
https://example.com/subdomain/subdomain2
https://example.com/domain`

Comment: @faceoff ohh I see. You can do that with `(?:^|[ \t])https:\/\/example\.com\/(?:[ \t]|$)`. Here's a [**live demo**](https://regex101.com/r/2v8BIj/1).